# Downloading pdfs with python?

Tags: python, pdf, download

I'm writting a script that uses regex to find pdf links on a page then download said links. The script runs and names the files properly in my personal directory however it is not downloading the full pdf file. The pdfs are being pulled and are only 19kb, a corrupted pdf, when they should be approxemtely 15mb

```
import urllib, urllib2, re

url = 'http://www.website.com/Products'
destination = 'C:/Users/working/'
website = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = website.read()
links = re.findall('.PDF">.*_geo.PDF', html)

for item in links:
    DL = item[6:]
    DL_PATH = url + '/' + DL
    SV_PATH = destination + DL
    urllib.urlretrieve(DL_PATH, SV_PATH)
```

The url variable links to a page with links to all the pdfs. When you click on the pdf link it takes you to 'www.website.com/Products/NorthCarolina.pdf' which displays the pdf in the browser. I'm not sure if because of this i should be using a diffrent python method or module

Comment: Have you looked in the files that you're downloading to see if they are actually pdfs, or are they web pages that have a message (such as an attempt at a redirect or some other HTTP status)?

Comment: what's in that 19K? It could be a download page w/ the link embedded.

Comment: That 19k, what was downloaded is a corrupted PDF file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import requests


links = ['link.pdf']
for link in links:
    book_name = link.split('/')[-1]
    with open(book_name, 'wb') as book:
        a = requests.get(link, stream=True)

        for block in a.iter_content(512):
            if not block:
                break

            book.write(block)
```

Comment: Thank you! A stupid mistake on my part. My code above works now as well as yours. The path of the web page with the pdf links was not the same as the path of the pdf. They were slightly different. The Error reporting in the requests module helped me realize that!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use HTML knowledge (for parsing) and the BeautifulSoup library to find all pdf files from a webpage and then download them all together.

```
html = urlopen(my_url).read()
html_page = bs(html, features=”lxml”)
```

After parsing, you can search for `<a>` tags since all hyperlinks have these tags. Once you have all the `<a>` tags, you can further narrow them down by checking if they end with the `pdf` extension or not. Here's a full explanation for it: https://medium.com/the-innovation/notesdownloader-use-web-scraping-to-download-all-pdfs-with-python-511ea9f55e48